# Pairwise comparisons after Glm.nb

Tags: r

I am studying some behavioral data based on the scan sampling method (number of occurrences of each behavior recorded among the total number of occurrences of all behaviors) in rabbits. I study two main effects that are the age of the animals (3 levels) and the time they are outside on a pasture (2 levels).

I have used this model for let's say the Grooming behavior:
glm.nb.Grooming = glm.nb(Grooming ~ Age * Time, data = sa)

The Anova showed an effect of age and time on the expression of this behavior (P_value(Time) < 0.05 and P_value(Age) < 0.05 with no effect of the interaction). I want to present my data in a table like this one down below because it exists an effect of Time x Age on some other behaviors.

When I want to run a "pairs" to know which values are different from the others, I get this problem (T3 and T8 are for Time outside and the numbers are the ages)

```
Grooming.em = emmeans(glm.nb.Grooming, ~ Time * Age, type="response") ; Grooming.em.em ; pairs(Grooming.em)
```

[image]

The pairwise comparisons has no p_value under 5% despite the effect of Age and Time as shown with the Anova.

I supposed it is because of some of the SE that are very high... or the log(0) I need to make these comparisons but I actually have no idea how to fix this. Can you help me? Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you don't have data for every age and time combination. Why not fit a model without interaction and follow-up with *separate* sets of EMMs and comparisons thereof for each main effect?

Comment: thank you Russ for your advice. That's what I did I just wrote a simplified model with only Time as the main effect for each age. And I don't have this problem any more. Thanks a lot

Comment: No, what I was suggesting is to fit the model `mod <- glm.nb(Grooming ~ Age + Time, data = as)`, then doing `emmeans(mod, "Age")` and `emmeans(mod, "Time")`. When factors don't interact, you don't need to look at each combination of them.